# Retrieve a certain value from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to retrieve certain value from a dictionary based on another value in the same dictionary.
Here is my code
The logic is if b== 5 then I would like to retrieve the value of 'a' in the same level of dictionary which should be 4.

```
dic = {'main':
           {'second_level':{
               'third_level_1':{
                'fourth_level_1':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3},
                'fourth_level_2':{'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6}
                 },
               'third_level_2':{
                'fourth_level_1':{'a':7, 'b':8, 'c':9},
                'fourth_level_2':{'a':14, 'b':15, 'c':16}
                 }
                }
           }
}

for key,value in dic['main']['second_level']['third_level_1']['fourth_level_2'].items():
    if value == 5:
        print(value of a?)
```

Comment: What is the question?  You are diving into the `dict` in a normal way. Are you not getting an output you expect? If it is something else please provide an expected input and expected output.

Comment: I try to get the value of key 'a'. I had key/value pairs for dic['main']['second_level']['third_level_1']['fourth_level_2'], if the value == 5 which is key/value pair 'b':5, I want the script to return me the value of 'a'. Is there any index for the key that I can use to refer it?

Comment: Just use the same dict reference.  
`search_dict = dic['main']['second_level']['third_level_1']['fourth_level_2']` --- `for key, value in search_dict:` --- `print(search_dict['a'])`

Answer (score 1):

```
for p_id, p_info in dic['main']['second_level']['third_level_1'].items():
    for key in p_info:
        if key=='b' and p_info[key]==5:
            print(p_info['a'])
```

In your code iteration is performed on fourth_level_2 so it's not possible to access fourth_level_2['a']. I am performing iteration on third_level_1 so it possible to access fourth_level_2['a'], it gives 4 as answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: explanation added